# Windows Phone 7 GetDistanceTo() returns incorrect distance

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

I am developing a small Windows Phone application. I am storing the current location of user in the database.

Here is the code to retrieve the current location which is stored in database.

```
public void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    CurrentLatitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString(); 
    CurrentLongitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString();
}
```

We need to allow user to do some activity if he is under the 400 meters from his saved location.

I am using the following code to calculate the distance.

```
internal double GetDistanceTo(GeoCoordinate ClientLocation)
{
    double distanceInMeter;

    GeoCoordinate currentLocation = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(watcher.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString()), Convert.ToDouble(watcher.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString()));
    distanceInMeter = currentLocation.GetDistanceTo(ClientLocation);

    return distanceInMeter;
}
```

ClientLocation : is the location saved in the database.

So my problem is that it gives extremly large distance even the user is standing at the same location(under 1 meter) which is saved in the database.

Example cordinates (extracted from device)

Saved in Database

> Lat : 29.8752546310425
>   Long: 73.8865985870361

Current Cordinates

> Lat : 29.8734102249146
>   Long :73.9049253463745
>
> Distance 
>   1780.45

Could anybody suggest me what is wrong here or a better way to get the distance between two coordinates?

Comment: GeoCoordinateWatcher exposes the MovementThreshold property. This property specifies the minimum change in position that must take place before the PositionChanged event is raised. In my case the movementThreshold was set to 10.0f meter which I now set to 1.0f meter so that I can get the correct data on a minimum position change.that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to [boulter.com](http://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=29.8734102249146,%2073.9049253463745&to=29.8752546310425,%2073.8865985870361&units=m) it is 1.11miles from A to B. Thats about 1780m, so I dont see what the problem is. Have a read of the [Moveable Type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) help on lat and long calculations.